# Titanium Alloy tableview

Tags: javascript, titanium

How do I get only one row checked in a tableview with 5 items.

So, when I click in an new row to turn off the olddest row.

Any help?

Thanks.n

Answer (score 0):

You must get all TableViewRow to deselect them.

Then mark the clicked row as check, like this for example :

```
function handleRow(e){

  //get all rows
  var allRows = $.tableview.data[0].rows;

  _.each(allRows, function(row){
    //uncheck row that was check
    if(row.hasCheck){
      row.hasCheck = false;
    }
  });

  //check the clicked row
  e.row.hasCheck = true;

}

$.tableview.addEventListener('click', handleRow);
```